# Delphi XE5 Android - Print in PDF

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I'm trying make a print-preview in PDF (prefered) with Delphi XE5 in Android.
founded a source to print but it's iOS

> find CCR.MacPDFWriter

To solve this problem i'm thinking to print in a image with Canvas.

What do you think? Anyone knows a better way or component to print-preview?